# HAProxy loadbalancing wildcards

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, wildcard, cloudflare

This is an example of my loadbalancer file for a single DNS entry.

```
acl:
  - 'is_site_net hdr(host) -i site.net’ 

use_backend:
  - 'site_net if is_site.net whitelist_list’

  site_net:
    options:
      server: ‘site_net 10.10.10.10:80'
```

I want to include an entry that uses wildcards, and wonder how to implement that in my file:

`*.demo.site.net`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't do wildcards AFAIK, but you can just match the tail of the address, which should do the same thing:

```
acl match_tail_example hdr_end(host) -i .demo.site.net
```

Comment: Should it not be a dot added `.demo.site.net`?

Comment: Ah, sorry for the typo.  Corrected.